# Reverse HTTP using HttpClient and existing tcp connection

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient

Is it possible to assign existing tcp connection for HttpClient to use?
Why this question?
I have "server A" with API behind NAT/Firewall and I did there outgoing connection  to "server B" which is public available. "server B" role is to consume "server A" API.
So, for not reinventing the wheel I would like to use .NET framework's HttpClient to consume "server A" API over existing tcp connection. How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about the "API" or the actual connection that is established with another endpoint?

Comment: Both, this established connection works as data forwarding to/from API. So when you send GET query from server B through this established connection it will be forwarded to API by using client connection on server A side. I have created and run helper application which runs on side A and it create two client connections: 1 - client connection to remote server B, 2 - client connection to local server A API. And I want to use HttpClient on side B on existing incoming connection made by helper application.

Comment: The HTTP client will want to manage its own connections as will any normal HTTP server (connection management is an explicit part of HTTP). In theory, one could write an HTTP proxy composed of two parts and install those two parts of the two relevant servers, then proxy all of the communications via that TCP connection but that would be far more work than you're probably expecting. There's nothing Out Of The Box for doing this that I can think of.

Comment: Yeah Damien, I did this kind of proxy u mentioned on server B side too. It opens listening port for every client connected to it and then HttpClient can query remote API via this local port on side B. BTW this works also if one like to redirect web site to other host but all concurrent requests from web browser must be quequed to send them one after one another response